# Using Fubini to prove $p\int_t^\infty\frac1{s^{p+1}}(\int_0^s w(x) \, dx) \, ds=\int_t^\infty\frac{w(s)}{s^p} \, ds+\frac{\int_0^tw(x) \, dx}{t^p}$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, fubini-tonelli-theorems

It was written that using Fubini's Theorem for a positive function $w$ and $p>0$, the following relation holds
\begin{equation*}
p\int_t^\infty \frac{1}{s^{p+1}}\left( \int_0^s w(x) \, dx\right)
\, ds=\int_t^\infty \frac{w(s)}{s^p} \, ds+\frac{\int_0^t w(x) \, dx}{t^p}.\tag1
\end{equation*}

My try for this, as follows by applying Fubini's Theorem

> \begin{eqnarray*}
> p\int_t^\infty \frac{1}{s^{p+1}}\left( \int_0^s w(x) \, dx\right)\, ds
> &=&p\int_t^\infty w(x)\left( \int_t^\infty \frac{1}{s^{p+1}}
> \, ds\right) dx \\
> &=&\int_t^\infty w(x)\left. \frac{1}{s^p}\right\vert_\infty^t \, dx
> \\
> &=&\int_t^\infty w(x)\frac{1}{t^p} \, dx.
> \end{eqnarray*}

Which obviously gives only one term from the required relation $(1).$
Any help with this, please.

Comment: You mixed up the intervals over which you want to integrate, your last expression does not even make sense anymore, as also your interval depends on $t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \int_t^\infty \frac{1}{s^{p+1}}\left( \int_0^s w(x) \, dx\right)
\, ds \\[12pt]
= {} & \iint\limits_{x,s\,:\,t\,<\, s\ \&\ 0\,<\,x\,<\, s} \frac 1 {s^{p+1}} w(x) \, d(x,s) \\[12pt]
= {} & \iint\limits_{\big(x,s\,:\,t\,<\,x\,<\,s\big)} + \iint\limits_{\big( x,s\,:\,0\,< \,x\, < \,t\,<\,s\big)}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you wrote LHS in two different ways (messing with $x$ and $t$).

The correct solution should look something like this
$$p\int\limits_t^\infty\frac{1}{s^{p+1}}\left( \int\limits_0^s w(x)dx \right)
ds=p\int\limits_0^t w(x) \left( \int\limits_t^\infty \frac{1}{s^{p+1}} ds \right)dx+
p\int\limits_t^\infty w(x) \left( \int\limits_x^\infty \frac{1}{s^{p+1}} ds \right)dx.$$

Simplifying these two integrals (the same way you did in the question body) will give you the right identity.

---

(edit)

You asked for details in a comment. Fubini's theorem allows us to compute a double integral over some domain as an iterated integral. In your problem we are given an iterated integral. It gives us a domain over which a double integral is taken. In the picture it is the red domain $D$. It looks like that, because we know that $s$ must run from $t$ to $+\infty$ and $x$ must run from $0$ to the line given by $s=x$. Since double integral is additive, we can write $\iint\limits_D\dots=\iint\limits_A\dots+\iint\limits_B\dots$, where $A$ and $B$ are respectively blue and green domains from the picture. Now for each of them we use Fubini's theorem: domain A is obtained when $x$ runs from $0$ to $t$ and $s$ runs from $t$ to $+\infty$. It gives us the first iterated integral in the RHS. Domain $B$ is obtained when $x$ runs from $t$ to $+\infty$ and $s$ runs from line $s=x$ to $+\infty$. It gives us the second iterated integral in the sum in the RHS. Is the solution clear now? [image]

Comment: Could you give some details, how did you get the two integrals on the right-hand side for your solution, please?

Comment: @MathLover Sure, I will edit my answer adding a picture

Comment: Really thanks for your time and effort